# Google Calendars in Outlook 365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, windows-10-calendar-app

I've recently bought the Office 365 subscription and have been trying to synchronize all Google calendars with the Outlook application. Found this official help https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/see-your-google-calendar-in-outlook-c1dab514-0ad4-4811-824a-7d02c5e77126, but I have each calendar manually.

Free Windows 10 Calendar app easily opens them all.

Internet is full of 3rd-party apps which do synchronization, but I cannot believe it couldn't be done without them.

Comment: Please check if the answer below is helpful. If your problem has been fixed, you could share your solutions or mark the best answer.

Comment: It brings insight and confirms what I've found, so I've given it an upvote. However, I found out that the Mac version of Outlook can import calendars (from Google and iCloud). This option is available for iOS and Android as well. But was not able to do the same on Windows

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any docs or similar thread about the differences between Windows 10 Mail/Calendar app and Outlook for desktop.

However, based on my test, if I added a gmail account to Outlook even if I manually chosed the Google account type:

[image]

Outlook will still add this account with IMAP (I think it's by design):

[image]

As far as the windows 10 Mail/Calendar app, if we manually choose the Google account type, all calendars will show in the Calendar panel. However, there will be no calendars synchronized to Outlook if we add the gmail account via IMAP:

[image]

Therefore, if we use Outlook to add a gmail mailbox, Outlook will automatically use IMAP. As **Roady** said in the following thread, IMAP protocol itself doesn't support Calendars: **[Outlook 2016 - How do I add a Full-Function Calendar to IMAP Account?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/596a643e-d30c-40b6-ae79-6a2cae2d2f86/outlook-2016-how-do-i-add-a-fullfunction-calendar-to-imap-account?forum=outlook)**

It seems that you could only refer to the official docs to add the gmail calendars, maybe there is an add-in which can help you sync all the gmail calendars: **[Connect Gmail Calendar to Outlook](https://www.slipstick.com/tutorial/connect-gmail-calendar-outlook/)**

Answer (score 0):

Which is different with outlook for windows, there seems to be an enhanced feature in outlook for mac: ***In order to enhance your Google, Yahoo, iCloud, and IMAP experience in Mail and Calendar for Windows 10 and Outlook for Mac, you can now sync your account to the Microsoft Cloud. This allows you to enjoy many of the best features of Mail and Calendar and Outlook for Mac, which were previously only available to those with Outlook.com, Microsoft 365, or Exchange Server email accounts.***

The following related docs is for your reference: **[Sync your account to the Microsoft Cloud](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-your-account-to-the-microsoft-cloud-985f9e19-d308-4e85-9d1d-0c6f32f8e981#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to,Server%20email%20accounts.%C2%A0)**